# Moving an item to the middle of a carousel when it's clicked in jquery/javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, carousel

I made a carousel that works fine, but now I want to make the item I clicked move to the middle of the carousel, i.e. the carousel should move until the item I clicked is centered in the middle.

View my work so far here: http://jsfiddle.net/HkTks/6/

I'm using the `animate()` but don't know if I should use `left`, `marginLeft`, or `scrollLeft` property. I'm really stuck as I don't know what logic to do, I don't even know where to begin. Please, shed me some light.

Many thanks

Comment: Great plugin. Im just wondering if your carousel container dosent have an equal amount of "items", and you want to center one - then there would be half "items" on both ends - which "breaks" the carousel look. So im wondering if that is the best choice? For example now there is 4 items .. so if you want to center 1 of them that would mean 3 items visible and ½ on each side.

Comment: Thanks @MarcoJohannesen, that's the problem I don't know how to do the logic to center the item... I'm lost.

Answer (score 0):

I've done something similar before, it's finicky, but it's just a few sums.
No time to test it in your code though.

> $('.iconsList li').click(function(){
>
> // next two should be one line
>
> var newLeftPos = 0 -(($(this).width() + $(this).css('margin-right')) * ($(this).index + 1)) + ($(this).parents('.iconsList').width() / 2);
>
> $('.iconsList li').animate({'left', newLeftPos + 'px'},400);
>
> })